# Access method binded by ref vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to access a method from a component. The component has a dynamic ref attached to it:

```
<team-card
              :ref="`team-card-details-${team.id}`"
              class="mt-5"
              v-for="team in teams"
              v-on:delete-team="DELETE_TEAM"
              :show-delete-btn="true"
              :key="team.name"
              :team="team"></team-card>
```

**team-card component**

```
methods: {
            REFRESH_CARD(){
                this.$refs[`team-card-details-component-${this.team.id}`].refreshcard()
      },
            REMOVE_REFRESH_ANIMATION(){
                this.$refs[`team-card-details-component-${this.team.id}`].removeRefreshAnimation()
      }
    }
```

Whenever I click a button in the card I would like to access `REFRESH_CARD` function which I'm doing with this line:

```
this.$refs['team-card-details-' + team.id].REFRESH_CARD()
```

I'm getting an error `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs[("team-card-details-" + team.id)].REFRESH_CARD is not a function"`

I have done the same in another method (but not to a dynamically generated ref). Does anyone have any suggestion why I'm getting this error?

If I do a simple `console.log` I can see the function present and the component being correctly referenced:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you are calling `REFRESH_CARD` before the ref exists?  Note that your `console.log` evaluated the ref lazily, so it may not have existed at the time that your error is showing up.

Comment: I find it hard to believe because when the page is loaded the component is rendered, and I have to manually click a button to call a function

Comment: @0x5453 I posted an answer and I'm not sure why this behaviour is happening. Do you happen to have some light on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but `refs` returned an array and I have to access the first position of the array (which I'm not so sure why but will update the answer if I find out why). So the final code would be like:

```
this.$refs['team-card-details-' + team.id][0].REFRESH_CARD()
```

**EDIT**

As @0x5453 have pointed out via the link

> When used on elements/components with v-for, the registered reference
>   will be an Array containing DOM nodes or component instances.

Comment: Based on [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref), it looks like using `ref` and `v-for` on the same component will give you an array of child components instead of one ref per key.

Comment: @0x5453 edited the question to insert your reference. Thank you for